# Idiomacy of the phrase "to be failing in one's duty"

Tags: idioms-in-context

[my question derives from one having been put up here before]

Are the components of the phrase "to be failing in one's duty" in solid idiomatic connection with each other. I.e. can "duty" be used here only in the meaning of "obligation, liability; fealty, loyalty".

Or can the phrase also convey the idea of "wriggling out of (shirking) one's task" or "falling down on (bungling, muddling) one's task" performed in an office or elsewhere? For example: "If the owner puts him in as a manager he will be falling down on (will be bungling) his duty (task, charge)".

Answer (score 1):

When you fail in your duty, you don't do what you are supposed to, or what other people expect you to do. There are many ways you can do so, either intentionally or due to your incapacity, incompetence, negligence, clumsiness, or ignorance.

It doesn't convey any of the ideas you suggested because it doesn't implicitly explain the reason(s) of a failure. These can usually be inferred from the context.

> The government is failing in its duty to protect people.

It could be a negligent corrupted administration or it could be that the state is at war and the problems have piled up. Either way, it's failing in its duties to keep people safe.

Comment: When one is failing in his duty intentionally, isn't it close to "shirking his duty"? And can't "duty" be understood as "a part of work, task carried out in his office"?

Answer (score 0):

Failing in one's duty implies a professional or official duty that one assumes and then **fails to carry out through carelessness or indifference,** NOT deliberately abandoning or betraying that duty.

It's absolutely not consistent with ' "wriggling out of (shirking) one's task"'

Shirking duty is also deliberate.
"Not up to the task" is related.

"The Department fails at it's duty."
Could be the Department, or the ones funding it, not the front line people, unless they were given the resources and failed to apply them.
One could fail at one's duty through deliberately not assigning adequate resources to a task--it reflects on the ones **failing to assign resources**, not those valiantly trying and failing.

So in regard to Covid, the US Government, especially the president failed in the duty to protect people. The CDC did likewise, failing to account for the importance of superspreaders and aerosol spread, and in failing to get a test ready quickly. They also failed to say clearly and early that there was a problem, and what needed to be done.

They deferred to the president and in doing so failed in their duty to the nation. They had enough resources, and where they didn't, didn't demand more.

Comment: The ambiguity of understanding of "duty" arose by me with the sentence "If Mary tells John the details of her job, she will be failing in her duty". What meanings of "duty" can the situation in the sentence refer to?

Comment: Is Mary a secret agent or on some undercover assignment? That's the only way that makes sense to me. I could make a case for this in terms of  industrial espionage,as well, if knowing a solid state specialist in superconducting materials was working on a particular project would reveal they're using superconductivity to solve some problem, but it feels like a real stretch to make that case.  Also possible her boss is howling-at-the-moon paranoid/crazy.

Comment: Just btw, the use of 'by me' above is not idiomatic US English. You could leave it out as implied, or say, "for me" or more commonly "In my case".

Comment: That is what exactly makes it an interesting case for a non-native speaker. What Mary is stays unknown. As for me ( being a non-native) I can perceive it in the following way: "Mary and John had been commissioned with making out a draught of an important document by their boss. Mary told him the details of her work in this direction. Having taken knowledge of it John covertly carried out the job first. So Mary failed in her duty (of preparing documents).

Comment: I am very grateful to you for the remark about "by me". It's of the utmost rareness here when someone corrects the text. Often it is more useful than the answer itself. And what is not idiomatic US English. Is it that "by me" can be in use in some areas of the USA or within some social groups only?

Comment: Usually used as "That's ok by me." (I approve)  Or "Run that by me before you send it out," usually referring to a written opinion or other piece of work. Or you would use 'by me' describing who had done something, "the photos are by me, but Laura arranged them and  did the writing." Usually one would say 'to me' (looks ok to me or 'for me' (For me the question is, what Mary does.)

Comment: Understood. And what do you think about my version about Mary, John and their boss?

Comment: If John did her job first without telling her, she did not fail. He's trying to hog the credit, but  that's not her fault.

Comment: One more of my perceptions, if you please. (the situation unwinds in the present time and you and me are mulling it) -  "I think if Mary's telling John the details of her job it demonstrates that she is uncapable of carrying out the duty by herself and by it she asks implicitly so that he may help her". I.e. if Mary is telling John the details of her job it would be that she is failing in her duty (and she is implying that John may help her in her duty).